# Style Android ActionMode bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

I'm trying to style the `ActionMode` bar.  I want the bar to remain the same except for some margin on the right (end).

```
<style name="GalleryActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.ActionMode">
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">56dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">56dp</item>
</style>
```

I'm not interested in the padding, but I used it as a test and the padding adjustment works.  Margin, however, has no effect.  I imagine this might be related to some unusual way it enters the existing layout.  Is there some way to style the *layout* of the `ActionMode` bar?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do this natively, but in my searching I found a great (and tiny) library that can be used as a replacement for the CAB that behaves more like a toolbar.  It was easily customizable and almost plugs right into the existing CAB model.

https://github.com/afollestad/material-cab/